# Prove $xy\notin H\cup K$ if $x\in H\backslash K$ and $y\in K\backslash H$ ($H,K$ subgroups)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to prove this statement for some exercise from my group theory course:

> Being $G$ group, and $H,K\leq G$. If $H\nsubseteq K$ and $K\nsubseteq
> > H$, then  $$x\in H\backslash K, y\in K \backslash H \implies xy\notin H\cup K.$$

I don't know if this is trivial. It seem trivial to me, but I'm not sure. How can I prove this?

Comment: If you are not sure how to prove it, then it is not trivial.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $xy\in H\cup K$.
Case 1: $xy\in H$. Since $x\in H$, we have $y=x^{-1}(xy)\in H$; which is a contradiction since $y\notin H$.

Can you complete the proof for Case 2 where $xy\in K$?

Comment: Yes, I can see it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Note that $y=x^{-1}\cdot xy$ and $x=xy\cdot y^{-1}$.